# How do I expose functions I add to a file that I created with cocoa pods?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm sure this question has been answered but I have no idea how it would be worded so please bear with me, clearly I have a lot to learn about using libraries as this is my first time.  I downloaded a library with pod install and am now trying to edit a class in it, but the function I add isn't exposed to my code outside of the pod file.  Mind you, the pod came with a bunch of other files but I can't find any references to the other public variables of this class in them so I'm not sure how they are exposed to my outside code but the function I am creating (its the really obviously named one is not).  Please help me

```
import UIKit

@objc public protocol WDImagePickerDelegate {
    @objc optional func imagePicker(imagePicker: WDImagePicker, pickedImage: UIImage)
    @objc optional func imagePickerDidCancel(imagePicker: WDImagePicker)
}

@objc public class WDImagePicker: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, WDImageCropControllerDelegate {
    public var delegate: WDImagePickerDelegate?
    public var cropSize: CGSize!
    public var resizableCropArea = false

    public func myCustomFunctionAddedAfterPodInstall(){
       print("hello world")
    }

    override public init() {
        super.init()
        print("WD was installed")
        self.cropSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 320)
        _imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        _imagePickerController.delegate = self
        _imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that if you ever update this library, all of the changes you've made will be wiped out.

Comment: Right if I pod install things will go back.  I am doing this because the library isn't swift 3 compatible.  Any why my function isn't publicly exposed though?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate it, hold on.

Comment: I got it working no problem. XCode complained that there was no such function, but once I built and ran it, it worked fine. I literally just copied your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that XCode will not autocomplete that custom function, and it even gave a "no such function" error before I built and ran it. Once I did that, however, everything worked fine. Here's my code:

WDImagePicker.swift:

```
@objc open class WDImagePicker: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, WDImageCropControllerDelegate {
    open var delegate: WDImagePickerDelegate?
    open var cropSize: CGSize!
    open var resizableCropArea = false

    public func myCustomFunctionAddedAfterPodInstall(){
        print("hello world")
    }

    ...
}
```

In my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    imagePicker = WDImagePicker()
    imagePicker?.cropSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: 90)
    imagePicker?.delegate = self

    imagePicker?.myCustomFunctionAddedAfterPodInstall()

    self.present((imagePicker?.imagePickerController)!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Wow thats so weird, yeah I got the same thing, I guess because I had another error I had mistakenly thought that this function was the problem.  Thank you for going through all that trouble, I was stuck for some time!

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to think that XCode is omniscient, but it's just another piece of software... it can have bugs just like anything you or I write.